# How do I render text In DirectX 11 using the C language

Tags: directx, directx-11

I've been trying to render some simple text on screen using DirectX 11, but I am unable to do It because I keep running into issues. I am using C18 and not C++. Have tried using DirectXTK , Direct2D and DirectWrite but none of these work. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: "Have tried using DirectXTK , Direct2D and DirectWrite but none of these work". Yes, they do work. Show us some code or what you've tried and failed.

Comment: I'm unable to use their data Structures as they're composed of classes and not structures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DirectX programming in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696079/directx-programming-in-c)